# Wordpress CPT slug and page slug conflicts

Tags: rewrite-rules, slug

I have one page slug "new-site" also i have another custom post type with same slug "new-site" while i browse site http://example.com/new-site then it directally goes to archive page and show all the posts from CPT new site.

How can i solve if i open with this url to page http://example.com/new-site
and http://example.com/new-site/post-slug for cpt post detail.

Thanks

Comment: And the archive of CPT? Do you want it?

Comment: I dont need archive CPT, i just need to open page while i enter http://example.com/new-site and i need CPT single page while i open http://example.com/new-site/post-slug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't need the CPT archvie, the easiest way to use `example.com/new-site` to open a page, and `example.com/new-site/post-slug` to open single posts of "new-site" post type, is to declare `has_archive => false` when registering the CPT:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cyb_register_cpt' );
function cyb_register_cpt() {
    $args = array(
      // .....
      'has_archive' => false
    );
    register_post_type( 'new-site', $args );
}
```

PD: Remember to flush the rewrite rules:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cyb_register_cpt' );
function cyb_register_cpt() {
    $args = array(
      // .....
      'has_archive' => false
    );
    register_post_type( 'new-site', $args );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, function () {
    cyb_register_cpt();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
} );

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, function () {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
} );
```